# How to check if two filenames are similar and select the latest version

Tags: python, nltk

I have a messy folder structure with a lot of files and people having saved a lot of versions of these files over time, something like:

```
Our awesome presentation v0.pptx
our_awesome_presentation v1.pptx
Our_Awesome_Presentation_vF.pptx
```

I'd like to pick one of these files and discard the rest, using python. There are potentially tens of thousands of such files with thousands of unique documents. I do NOT need to be 100% accurate in picking the files, so I think for selecting files it's enough for me to look at file creation date or last modified date. If I miss a few files that are similar (i.e., if I pick up two versions of the same file thinking they are two different files), that's also fine. In short, I don't need to be perfect, I just want to reduce the size of the folder while retaining as much unique information as I can.

Now I am thinking I need some sort of string similarity score for filenames. What is a good way to do this? Can I use something like nltk? How?

Comment: Have you looked at **fuzzywuzzy** and **rapidfuzz**  modules which will give a string similarity score using Levenshtein distance?

Answer (score 2):

> similarity score for filenames

First, put filenames in standard form:

```
    name = name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
```

Something along those lines.

Next, as you scan through sorted names,
compute length of common prefix
between `current` name and `previous` name.
For successive pairs where that is above a threshold,
say 50% of name length, use that to group
"same name, different suffix" filespecs together.

For each file group, your "most recent modification time"
rule will pick the group's winner.

---

For something fancier than a "common prefix" ratio, use an
[edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)
on successive sorted pairs, perhaps the
[Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance.

Comment: Based on the threshold "our_awesome_presentation_v1.pptx" and "awesome_presentation_v0.pptx" woud be in the same file group, right? I know OP said "don't want a perfect solution" but I feel like this would combine unrelated groups and discards one of them. But there's no perfect solution for this problem because two presentations might contain totally different "projects" but the name of them can be similar. :^)

Comment: Yeah, I considered the "prepend a new word" issue when writing this up, and decided to lump it because OP didn't require perfection and I wasn't willing to (1.) suffer quadratic all-pairs comparison performance, and (2.) word tokenization would complicate the solution. But yeah, we could parse each filename into words, sort the filename's words, put those in a giant temp file which we sort, and then we're back to O(N) comparison of sorted records, robust against prefix injection. Naïvely we might lexically sort words within filename, but sorting by descending word length would be better.

Comment: So far this is the only feasible solution I have (combined with taking the levenshtein ratio on successive files). But yeah still wondering if there is a good way to handle versions with a word/character appended toward the front

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Levenshtein ratio to determine the similarity between two strings (filenames in this case). If the ratio is high (e.g., >= 0.95) then you can reasonably say that the two strings are very similar. Then you would choose one of the two strings to reject.

You will need: *pip install levenshtein*

Then, for example:

```
from Levenshtein import ratio
from functools import cache

paths = [
    'Our awesome presentation v0.pptx',
    'our_awesome_presentation v1.pptx',
    'Our_Awesome_Presentation_vF.pptx',
    'Banana republic.txt',
    'Very important.docx',
    'Our_Awesome_Presentation vK.pptx'
]

@cache
def normalise(s):
    return s.lower().replace(' ', '_')

R = 0.95

remove = set()

for i, a in enumerate(paths[:-1], 1):
    for b in paths[i:]:
        if ratio(a, b, processor=normalise, score_cutoff=R) >= R:
            remove.add(a)
            break

print(*(set(paths) - remove), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Our_Awesome_Presentation vK.pptx
Very important.docx
Banana republic.txt
```

Comment: The files are chronologically sorted, right?

Comment: @doneforaiur The question asks "Now I am thinking I need some sort of string similarity score for filenames". That's effectively what this code does. It could easily be extended to check the two "similar" filenames to check the last modification time and delete the oldest (if that makes sense for the use-case)

Comment: I considered scanning the whole corpus with an [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) like Levenshtein, and rejected that due to quadratic badness. OP reports something like 10^4 or 10^5 filenames to examine. I was unwilling to compute 10^8 or 10^10 all-pairs distance metrics. Now, _within_ a group I agree it's a terrific technique. But we need something to put group elements together, maybe character- or word- based N-gram scoring, or [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). Using it on successive sorted names finds group boundaries, modulo prefix edits.

Comment: @J_H My suggested answer is undoubtedly going to be inefficient for large data sets which, admittedly, OP says she is using but I still think it would work

Comment: Yes, I think I need a faster way to get file groups.